# Covering irregular region with circles

Tags: python, geometry

I have the following image (mask),

[image]

which I would like to fill with circular regions like so,

[image]

In this particular example I manually created circles using a step in X & Y direction and only kept a circle if 95% of it falls in the white region. However I would like to maximise the coverage of the map. I assume this can be achieved by randomly generating the centres of the circles and aim to maximise the coverage. I don't mind if the regions overlap a bit if I can further maximise the used area

Are there any suggestions as to how I can tackle this problem or if there are any algorithms that can do that for me?

Comment: Filling or covering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) problem and is notoriously difficult.

If you don't care about the exact boundaries and want to maximize coverage, you should use a [hexagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) which gives you a ~90.69% coverage.

You could do it something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = misc.imread('xZoI6.png')

ys, xs, _ = image.shape

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xs), np.arange(ys), sparse=True)

radius = 20.0

for i in range(int(-0.5 * ys / radius), int(xs / radius)):
    for j in range(int(ys / radius)):
        x0 = 2 * radius * (i + 0.5 * j)
        y0 = 2 * radius * np.sqrt(3)/2 * j

        r = np.sqrt((x - x0) ** 2 + (y - y0) ** 2)

        indicator = r < radius

        if np.any(image[indicator, 0] != 0):
            image[r < radius] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

plt.imshow(image)
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [hexagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) with appropriate dimension and draw a circle at the center of every hexagon.